# how to change font size and font name of uisegmentedcontrol programmatically on swift?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

How to change font size and font name of uisegmentedcontrol programmatically? I used swift.

Here is my code:

```
self.mysegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: [
        NSLocalizedString("Aaaaaa", comment: ""),
        NSLocalizedString("Bbbbbb", comment: ""),
        NSLocalizedString("Cccccc", comment: ""),
        NSLocalizedString("Dddddd", comment: ""),
        NSLocalizedString("Eeeeee", comment: ""),
        ])
self.mysegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "mysegmentedControlDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
self.mysegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
```

regards.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

UI can use control appearance, best place to add it is in app delegate, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, use this if you want to set up the same attribute to every UISegmentedControls in your project just once:

```
let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , forState: .Normal)
```

But if you are going to set up attributes to just one UISegmentedControl or if you want to change it more often base on some condition use this, UISegmentedControl method:

```
func setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]?,
                   forState state: UIControlState)
```

Example:

```
let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
seg.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Can i edit UISegmentedControl size too (i mean width and height) programmatically in app delegate? If it can, how to do it?

Comment: I'd suggest using auto layout and add a NSLayoutConstraint to each SegmentedControl

Comment: +1 for suggesting UIAppearance proxy, -1 for suggested to insert into the app delegate. The timing is important, to do it before loading any other views, so it should be done prior to the finish of `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, but it's better architecture to move all your presentation logic to a different class that's sole responsibility is presentation and style.

Answer (score 29):

For Swift 4

```
    let font: [AnyHashable : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(font, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Where do you write the font name?

Comment: I used this instead ( Swift 5 )



`let fontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
        segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 21):

This answer is dated, but for those who are looking for a solution in swift you might want to try this approach:

```
func stylizeFonts(){
    let normalFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let boldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 16.0)

    let normalTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: normalFont!
    ]

    let boldTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : boldFont!,
    ]

    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Normal)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Highlighted)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(boldTextAttributes, forState: .Selected)
}
```

Be sure to add stylizeFonts() in your viewDidLoad or as a separate function if you are subclassing.

Comment: FYI, you have an extra comma within let boldTextAttributes after boldFont!

Answer (score 11):

**Greg**'s answer updated for Swift3:

```
let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 8):

@Jordan Montel answer updated for Swift 5. Working code to change font and font size.

```swift
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func font(name:String?, size:CGFloat?) {
        let attributedSegmentFont = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: name!, size: size!)!, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSCopying)
        setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject] as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

usage "segControl" is what ever your IBOutlet name is:

```swift
segControl.font(name: "Your Font Name", size: 10)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 2.0**

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let attributedSegmentFont = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 14.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)

    dashBoardSegment.setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
    }
```

**Changing for all segment controls, use:**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
```

**Using Swift Extension:**

```
extension UISegmentedControl{
    func changeTitleFont(newFontName:String?, newFontSize:CGFloat?){
        let attributedSegmentFont = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: newFontName!, size: newFontSize!)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

**Implementing extension:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    dashBoardSegment.changeTitleFont("Roboto-Regular", newFontSize: 14.0)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift3**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 14.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Further to jeff-ziligy answer I have played around with the code and found an updated code for Swift 5.1:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

func setFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat) {

    let normalTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor as NSObject: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSObject : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    ]

    let boldTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor as NSObject : UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSObject : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium),
    ]

    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .normal)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .highlighted)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(boldTextAttributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], for: .selected)
  }
}
```

The part where up implement in the ViewDidLoad() is the same:

```
yourSegmentedControl.setFontSize(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the part about placing in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 4):

By way of extending mvien's excellent Swift approach. I've created a SegmentedControl extension:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    func setFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat) {

        let normalTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
        ]

        let boldTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize, weight: UIFontWeightMedium),
        ]

        self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Normal)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Highlighted)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(boldTextAttributes, forState: .Selected)
    }
}
```

Just add the above extension code to your project then use like this:

```
yourSegmentedControl.setFontSize(20)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font],
                                            for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
@IBOutlet var sgmentTypeSelect: UISegmentedControl!{
        didSet {

            let normalTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.themeGold,
                NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.defaultMontserratFont(style: "SemiBold", size: 13)
            ]

            let selectedTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
                NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.defaultMontserratFont(style: "Bold", size: 13)
            ]

            sgmentTypeSelect.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, for: .normal)
            sgmentTypeSelect.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, for: .highlighted)
            sgmentTypeSelect.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTextAttributes, for: .selected)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Alvin George answer because I think it is a great idea to add extension for manipulate that (and improve it for Swift 4) :

Create an extension class of UISegmentedControl like `UISegmentedControl+Additions.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UISegmentedControl {
    func font(name:String?, size:CGFloat?) {
        let attributedSegmentFont = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: name!, size: size!)!, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.font as NSCopying)
        setTitleTextAttributes(attributedSegmentFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Use it in your code :

```
segmentedControl?.font(name: "My Font Name", size: 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Xamarin/C# Solution

Here's the breakdown for changing with UIAppearance based on the approved answer:

```
var font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 16f);
var textAttributes = new UITextAttributes { Font = font };
UISegmentedControl.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, 
    UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Objective-C** version:

```c
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17] };
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update version of [ziligy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3175000/ziligy) 's answer.

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func setFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat) {
        let normalTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .regular)
        ]
        
        let boldTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .medium)
        ]
        
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, for: .highlighted)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(boldTextAttributes, for: .selected)
    }//end method
    
}//end extension
```

Answer (score -2):

For swift 3

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for: .selected)
```