# How to retrieve the font of a UISegmentedControl's title programmatically?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont

I need to use a UIFont extension on a UISegmentedControl's title, but in order to do so, I have to get access to the UISegmentedControl's title font programmatically.

How can I do that?

I tried to create an instance of a label, and then assign the UISegmentedControl's title to the text of that label but it's not the proper way to do it.

here's my attempt:

```
let segmentTitle = segmentedControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(0)
let label = UILabel()
label.text = segmentTitle
```

I'm looking for a better way to do that ?

Comment: What is UIFont you want to use? You can referent to some question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940042/how-to-change-font-size-and-font-name-of-uisegmentedcontrol-programmatically-on Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Your title and part of the question states you want to retrieve the font. But the bulk of your question implies you want to set the font. Please clarify.

Comment: @rmaddy I need to get the width of the font of the title that is inside the UISegmented control by using a UIFont extension method.so  I want to know how can I retrieve that title font programmatically ( I will update my question for more clarity )

Answer (score 0):

The method you’re looking for is [`-setTitleTextAttributes:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:).

```
let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [ NSFontAttributeName: myFont ]
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState:.Normal)
```

For the full list of keys you can use in the attributes dictionary, see the [Character Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes) section of the UIKit NSAttributedString reference.