# How to change font size for UISegmentedcontrol's title?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

How to change font size for segmentedcontrol's title?

[image]

Comment: see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940042/how-to-change-font-size-and-font-name-of-uisegmentedcontrol-programmatically-on

Comment: thank you! @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Consider posting as answer @Anbu.

Comment: @StephanKristyn They DID post an answer, and it was removed as NAA (link-only).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the font size by using two approaches.

1.) Update font using `appearance` proxy of `UISegmentControl`. This will update same property for all objects of `UISegmentContol` of your app.
You don't need to set in every viewController, just set in `didFinishLaunching:` of `appDelegate`.

```
var attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "yourFontName", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attr, forState: .Normal)
```

2.) Update font for specific segment control.

```
var attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "yourFontName", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
self.statusSegmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr, forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
yourSegControl.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 18.0)! ], forState: .Normal)
```

You can find out more in the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   var attributes = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
    segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
```